# Basic javascript error

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
<script type='text/javascipt' language="javascript">
    function getUserLoc() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayResult, displayError);
        }
        else {
            setMessage("Geolocation is not supported by this browser");
        }
    }
    function displayResult(position) {
        setMessage("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + ", Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);
    }
    function setMessage(msg) {
        document.forms[0].myLoc.value = msg;
    }
    function displayError(error) {
        var errors = { 1: 'Permission denied', 2: 'Position unavailable', 3: 'Request timeout' };
        setMessage("Error occured: " + errors[error.code]);
    } 
</script>
```

As well as this in ASP.NET:

```
<asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" Text="Log In" ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup"
            OnClientClick="getUserLoc( )"  />
```

However when I click the 'LoginButton' I get the JavaScript error: `getuserlock is undefined`

Comment: "it's not worked" is *never* enough information. You need to say what you expected to happen, and what actually happened.

Comment: What is the error. I would removed the ( ) on the getUserLoc to see if that works. But is it actually getting to the JS function or not even firing?

Comment: when i click log in button, it says  ' getuserlock is undefined'

Comment: Have you tried `*gasp*` _using a debugger?_

Comment: Please at least paste the actual generated HTML/JS markup.

Comment: @wide, that would be because the function is named `getUserLoc`, not `getuserlock`, don't you think?

Comment: Are you sure you're calling the right javascript function? Code in your question defines getUserLoc(), but from your comment, it appears as if you had defined 'getUserLock'. Post your error message as well, please.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi, i correct it. bu still gives same error.

Comment: Have you tried fixing the typo in my answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a typo in your code. You have:

```
<script type='text/javascipt' language="javascript">
```

but it should be

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
```

(text/javascript)

Also, remove the unnecessary space in your method call because it can give the impression that there's supposed to be a parameter entered. (This isn't required, but more of a personal preference)

```
OnClientClick="getUserLoc();"
```

Comment: I agree, script type="text/javascipt" will never work :)

Comment: You can safely delete the type and language attributes - JavaScript will be assumed (though if you leave 'em in they should be spelled correctly). The space in the parentheses doesn't matter.

Comment: +1 In HTML5 you can even just eliminate both attributes.

Comment: @nnnnnn - True (updated answer which removes the language attribute). The space issue was more for readability than functionality, but that's down to personal preference.

Comment: Actually my preference is to remove it too (for readability), but I wasn't sure from the way you phrased that point whether you were saying it would stop the code working. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Re-reading it, I agree that there's some ambiguity there. Updated :)